# Stack Exchange: Block a site in "Filtered Questions" filters, or add a select all

Tags: feature-request, stackexchange.com, tag-filters

I've found that Stack Overflow likes to dominate the "My Sites" feed on "Filtered Questions". I've created a filter for all of the sites, without Stack Overflow. I just know that it would be nice to be able to use all sites *except* for ones that you don't want. I'm sure not everyone wants to take the time to click 80+ checkboxes. Even a "Select/Deselect All" in the site list would help.